# Trigger a Java REST endpoint upon S3 File Upload Event

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, kubernetes, spring-batch, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a Spring Batch application which does followings,

1. A different application puts a csv file in a S3 bucket INBOUND
2. Spring Batch application reads a csv file
3. using data of each row, it calls an API endpoint and get a quote
4. Put those quotes in a newly created csv and put in a S3 bucket OUTBOUND

Spring Batch Application Tech Stack

- Created using Spring Boot
- Spring Batch Job Launcher is called upon a REST endpoint
- Deployed in OpenShift

What I want to do,

When the other application puts a new file into the S3 INBOUND bucket it needs to trigger the Spring Batch Operation (call the REST endpoint which launches the job)

Can I do this using a K8s Cron Job which triggered by S3 events? If so can someone please explain how?
Or do I have any other options?

Comment: So if I try to summerize, you want to call a REST endpoint when a new file is added in a s3 bucket. Is that correct?

Comment: How big of the csv file?

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine,
Yeah, that's what I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too familiar with AWS services but I know that they provide a notification service for S3 buckets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

One of the event notification destinations is AWS Lambda. So you can try to create a function that calls the rest endpoint and which is triggered when a notification of type `ObjectCreated` arrives.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a lambda function which is triggered when a .txt file is uploaded into the S3 bucket's INBOUND folder.

Wrote a python handler to curl command to hit the job launcher REST end point.